# Is this a slop food?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

[image]

So I still haven't quite understood slop. So I was wondering if this mushroom soup is slop even though tastes good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, slop is what farmers feed swine. Imagine a small farm with only one or two pigs. They would often feed the pigs a lot of stuff that might otherwise go in the garbage. But the colloquial usage you are speaking of applies to nasty food served to humans - often those in prison or slaves. The photo you shared of your mushroom soup certainly *looks* like something one might call slop, but if it tasted good and was made from decent ingredients, you wouldn't refer to it as slop.